# connecting to derby database with tomcat as the server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, database-connection, derby

How do i connect to derby database *(that comes with the netbeans)* ? I am using Tomcat as the server. Earlier i used the following statements to connect to the derby database,but then i used `glassfish` as the server.

```
Context context = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource)context.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/PollDatasource");
Connection connection = ds.getConnection();
```

But now using Tomcat as the server i am unaware how to do this.

*Note : Tomcat and Derby are pre installed with netbeans IDE that i am using currently*

Comment: Have you *configure* JNDI dataSource?

Comment: @AVD no haven't configured that

Comment: Please refer this [url](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html) and @Raknel post.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Tomcat find *conf/context.xml*, then edit and write something like this:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/PollDatasource" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    driverClassName="com.YourDriver" 
    url="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/nameOfTheDatabase;create=true"
    username="username" password="password" maxActive="20" 
    maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1" />
```

***Note 1: With the above URL the driver will be `org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver`***

***Note 2 : You can also add the above information in META-INF/context.xml of your project. This becomes application specific.If you add the information in tomcat's context.xml that becomes global.***

***Note 3: Download the jar from [this website](http://db.apache.org/derby/releases/release-10.9.1.0.cgi).Download db-derby-10.9.1.0-bin.zip.It contains many files, including derby.jar and derbyclient.jar (along with much documentation).derbyclient.jar contains our friend `org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver.class`. derby.jar contains `org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver`. Keep the downloaded jar in lib folder of Tomcat.***

and in your application web.xml "resource-ref":

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>my connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/PollDatasource</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>
```

You may want to look at these questions :

- [Isn't it necessary to mention the name of archive in the Resource tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519715/isnt-it-necessary-to-mention-the-name-of-archive-in-the-resource-tag)
- [When is the tag I added in context.xml gets read?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544042/when-is-the-tag-i-added-in-context-xml-gets-read)
- [What are steps followed in the look-up? what is looked first web.xml or context.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553889/what-are-steps-followed-in-the-look-up)

Comment: This the name of the JDBC driver, specific for database. For your application that will be org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver. You can download this in jar from: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.derby/derby

Comment: I added these tags but get an [exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516747/org-apache-tomcat-dbcp-dbcp-sqlnestedexception-what-is-this-and-why-do-i-get-t)

Comment: can you please explain how are these tags looked up when attempting a connection. I have problem applying this and a problem understanding this

Answer (score 4):

You need to:

1) Copy your `derbyclient-*.jar` to `${TOMCAT_HOME}/lib`.

2) Edit your `server.xml` and add the following lines to the section GlobalNamingResources:

```
 <Resource auth="Container" 
           driverClassName="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" 
           maxActive="8" maxIdle="4" 
           name="jdbc/my-ds" type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
           url="jdbc:derby:mydb;create=true" 
           username="myuser" password="mypassword" />
```

3) In your context definition, add:

```
 <Context docBase="myapp"
          path="/myapp"
          reloadable="true"
          ...>
    <ResourceLink name="jdbc/my-ds"
                  global="jdbc/my-ds"
                  type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
 </Context>
```

4) Restart Tomcat.

Comment: [I added these tags but get an exception.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516747/org-apache-tomcat-dbcp-dbcp-sqlnestedexception-what-is-this-and-why-do-i-get-t)Though i have edited the `context.xml` of tomcat and `web.xml` in my project.

Comment: Upvoting this because I found it by accident and it fits really nicely in my current application.

Answer (score 1):

The example you have requires JNDI. See the relevant tomcat versions docs on setting that up.

Or use a connection string, here's a page from derby docs http://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/plugin_help/derby_app.html