# Getting Null for JDBC connection

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc

I am running tomcat 7.0.47 on my windows and there I am having the Mysql database connection to the data stored at BlueHost .When I run it locally it runs successully and makes conenction to the BlueHost database without any error .But when I try to deploy its war file at the linux environment running tomcat 7.0.42 it gives me following error:

```
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
```

Also , I have imported the tomcat.dbcp jar to the online server as linux has some issues with this jar .

```
Also, Server is working if I donot follow connection pooling approach .
```

I am not able to find out What can be the issue with  pooling ?

Following is my `context.xml` file:

```
  <Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/web_app">
   <Resource 
              name="jdbc/DB" 
              auth="Container" 
              type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
              maxActive="100" 
              maxIdle="30"  
              maxWait="10000"
              username="DBUser" 
              password="DBPassword"
              driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://xx.xx.xx.xx:xx/DB_app?useUnicode=true&#38;characterEncoding=UTF-8"/>
     </Context>
```

`web.xml`:

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>MySQL Datasource</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/DB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>
```

`DatabaseConnection.java`:

```
 public class Get_Database_Connection 
{

     static DataSource ds;
     public static Connection con=null;
     public static Connection get_DB_Connection() throws NamingException,SQLException
     {
           if(ds==null)
            {

            Context ctx = new InitialContext();
            ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/DB");  

           return ds.getConnection();
          }
            else
            {
            return ds.getConnection();
            } 
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like your linux environment isn't configured correctly.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Can you specify the where exactly I should look for in the linux environment . As I have added the jar required.

Comment: @Kanchan, is linux box's ip whitelisted for bluehost's MySQL access?

Comment: @Sridhar yes it is whitelisted

Comment: @Kanchan , examining tomcat's catalina.out file in logs folder might provide you some clue.

Comment: @Sridhar It is showing the error that I have written in the post .

Comment: @Kanchan at connection URL `...e=true&#38;ch...` is `#38;` exist? or it's just a typo here in the question?

Comment: It is there in my code @Yazan

Comment: @Kanchan then you have to remove it :) not sure if this is the reason, but it's definitely not correct and should be removed

Comment: But that url is working when i try to fetch the data without using connection pooling @Yazan

Comment: well, i told you i am not sure if this is the reason, maybe the pooling rejects the URL or whatever happens, my note that #38; should not be in the URL, you want to consider this note, or not, it's up to you.

Comment: it is giving me error if i remove it @Yazan

Comment: Since the context.xml you provided works with the provided version of Tomcat, my suspicion is that the Bluehost environment is either using a different version of Tomcat or a different version of context.xml.  My instinct is the latter.

Comment: (1) That `&#38;` can be safely - and more clearly - replaced with `&amp;`. (2) Do you have command line access to that linux machine? (3) When you said your IP is whitelisted, did you mean its internal IP (the one displayed with `ifconfig`) or its external one (one displayed with services like whatismyip.com)? If you are behind a firewall doing NAT the two may not be the same.

Comment: your `context.xml` is normally deployed to `{catalina-root}/conf/Catalina/localhost/{webapp-name}.xml`. Can you check if that file contains what you expect it to contain? It may be write-protected or whatever.

Comment: @RealSkeptic 1) ok, I will try with that . 2) I donot have command line access to the linux machine. 3) My domain name is whitelisted. Its not internal config IP .

Comment: @geert3 the file is not being created as expected.

Comment: @BalusC In catalina.out file , there is just : org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
sql exception:java.sql.SQLException: Error establishing connection!

Comment: There are no " root cause " or " caused by " parts

Comment: 1) META_INF/context.xml . 2) WEB_INF/lib/mysql-connector.jar

Comment: @BalusC   I tried it . But its giving same error .

Comment: @BalusC  Thanks for the information .I will try to figure out more information about the root cause.

Comment: @Kanchan i just came by this again, i had this idea, what about the permissions of `context.xml`,`META_INF` and `mysql-connector.jar`? try to give 777 for those,, who knows ... and and the owner too, if it's only root maybe Tomcat process can't access?!

Comment: @Yazan ok , I will try it .

Comment: @Kanchan may be this will be help ful only change the db from derby to mysql [and other url changes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11588580/2749470)

Comment: @BhargavModi I have gone through that link already . that is not helpful to me .

Comment: You said: "as linux has some issues with this jar" could you elaborate on what those issues were?  Also, what version of this jar are you using?  I suspect that other jars (maybe Apache Commons Pool) are required.  How are you building this war?  Either maven or gradle would help with such dependency management

Comment: @JoeG  packaging for tomcat7 lacks the tomcat-dbcp.jar file. I am using tomcat.dbcp 7.0.42 jar.  I have my project in netbeans and  it uses Ant to build the war .

Comment: If you found the answer please post it here..

Answer (score 2):

Based on Tomcat's [JDBC Connection Pool](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#JNDI_Factory_and_Type) to use connection pool you are required to configure factory attribute, so here is your updated context.xml configuration file:

```
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/web_app">
 <Resource name="jdbc/DB"
      auth="Container"
      type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
      maxActive="100"
      maxIdle="30"
      maxWait="10000"
      username="yourUsername"
      password="password"
      driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
      url="jdbc:mysql://xx.xx.xx.xx:xx/DB_app?useUnicode=true&#38;characterEncoding=UTF-8"/>
</Context>
```

Comment: Hi . I have tried this but tomcat at linux environment is ignoring context.xml file .