# Tomcat JNDI: Data Source fails to initialize

Tags: java, tomcat, database-connection, jndi

Common question, I know, but I can't figure it out. Tomcat 6.0.41 with a very standard setup, single host. When I try to get a JDBC database connection from a `DataSource`, I get the following error:

> org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver
>   of class '' for connect URL 'null'
>   ...
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver

**My JDBC driver jar file (MySQL Connector/J) is located at** `/usr/share/tomcat6/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar`.

Here's my context.xml file:

```
<context>

  <Resource name="jdbc/first_db" 
        auth="Container" 
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        maxActive="100" 
        maxIdle="30" 
        maxWait="10000"
        username="..." 
        password="..." 
        url="jdbc:mysql://my.host.com:3306/first_db"
        connectionProperties="verifyServerCertificate=false;useSSL=true;requireSSL=true"/>

  <Resource name="jdbc/second_db" 
        auth="Container" 
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        maxActive="100" 
        maxIdle="30" 
        maxWait="10000"
        username="..." 
        password="..."
        url="jdbc:mysql://my.host.com:3306/second_db"
        connectionProperties="verifyServerCertificate=false;useSSL=true;requireSSL=true"/>

</context>
```

I have this in my web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>First DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/first_db</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>

<resource-ref>
    <description>Second DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/second_db</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

In my code, I'm doing this:

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
dataSource = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/first_db");
Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection(); // error here
```

I've tried putting the `context.xml` in the following locations (my webapp root is located at `/var/www`):

- /etc/tomcat6/Catalina/locahost/context.xml
- /etc/tomcat6/Catalina/context.xml
- /var/www/WEB-INF/context.xml
- /var/www/WEB-INF/META-INF/context.xml
- /var/www/META-INF/context.xml

I've also tried adding my resource elements from the context.xml shown above to the global context config at `/etc/tomcat6/context.xml`. Everything I've tried results in the same JDBC error.

I just changed the JNDI lookup string in my code to something that doesn't exist, and I got this:

> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name doesNotExist is not bound in this Context

...so the fact that I don't normally see this error must mean that the `context.xml` file **is** being found and processed. So that means that Tomcat just can't find the MySQL driver. But it is **definitely** in `/usr/share/tomcat6/lib`. I updated the driver to the latest version just now (v5.1.35) but it still gives the same error.

I've also just removed the mysql driver jar file from my `WEB-INF/lib` directory, because some people are saying there might be an issue having it there **and** in the tomcat system lib directory. Still the problem though.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the mysql JDBC JAR in the Tomcat lib folder?

See this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556664/how-to-fix-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql-localhost-dbname-error-w).  It could be that Tomcat can't load the driver.

Comment: I do have the JDBC drivers in `/usr/share/tomcat6/lib`

Comment: Are you using Maven to ensure all dependencies are included in your WAR?

Comment: I'm not using Maven, but right now the file `/usr/share/tomcat6/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.14-bin.jar` exists and so does the file `/var/www/WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.14-bin.jar` (that's where my webapp dependencies are located).

Comment: I would check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516747/cannot-create-jdbc-driver-of-class-for-connect-url-null-i-do-not-underst). It looks like the same problem.