# Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null' Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat

I know this questions has  been asked before but the answers does not addressing the problem in my case.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516747/cannot-create-jdbc-driver-of-class-for-connect-url-null-i-do-not-underst](http://Cannot%20create%20JDBC%20driver%20of%20class%20'%20'%20for%20connect%20URL%20'null'%20:%20I%20do%20not%20understand%20this%20exception)

The answer selected by the user talks about the different approach, With the help of the suggested approach my application is working fine but I am want to do it in below manner.

Wanted to put my JNDI xml file containing db connection details in

```
 tomcat\7.0\conf\Catalina\localhost
```

and when I am running the tomcat from command prompt It should make a connection with the database. In this case my xml file name is application.xml. Running application from command prompt giving me error as

```
Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null' Oracle
```

Steps I have tried:

1. below is the XML file created JNDI resource:

`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Context path="/application" reloadable="false">
    <Logger className="org.apache.catalina.logger.FileLogger" prefix="application." suffix=".log" timestamp="true"/>
    <Resource name="jdbc/application" 
    factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
    username="abc"
    password="abc"
    driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@<<server_address>:1522:<<sid>>"
    maxActive="20" maxWait ="10000" maxIdle="10"/>             
    </Context>
```

` with the information

2. web.xml have a entry for the above resource as

> 

```
`<resource-ref>
    <description>Connection Pool</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/application</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>
```

`

3. Put ojdbc6.jar file in tomcat/lib folder.

I am making sure that I have not put ojdbc6.jar in both tomcat and my project and I am using oracle 12c as a database.

Comment: did you try to add '//' like this   jdbc:oracle:thin:@//<<server_address>:1522/<<sid>> ?

Comment: @vincent Just now tried..no luck :(.

Comment: Do you really have `<<sid>>` in the URL (literally)?

Comment: 12c multitenant? If it is a pluggable db do not use SID. Instead use SERVICE_NAME  @hostname:1522/SERVICE_NAME. By the way, always use SERVICE_NAME. Always.

Comment: can you show your java code where you are creating connection?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Nope, I am putting a proper Sid.

Comment: @BjarteBrandt: As suggested, Tried with service name also...but getting the same error.

Comment: @swapyonubuntu: The problem is not how i am making the connection, since application is working fine when i am creating the "context.xml " inside Meta-inf folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the filename. My application WAR name was "TomcatExample.war" and xml name was "tomcatexample.xml" It is case sensitive in tomcat 7 and that is the reason it was not picking up the file. Changes to "TomcatExample.xml" works for me.
Thank you so much all for your help.
Cheers!!!