# Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web13?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC'

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I created a properties file

```
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web13?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
username=root
password=root
```

and I created a connection pool

```
    private static DataSource dataSource; 
static {

    try {
        //load properties file
        InputStream is = DBCPUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("db.properties");
        //load input stream
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.load(is);
        //create data source
        dataSource = BasicDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(props);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Then I got the problem. I searched some anwsers, they said driver needs to be registered like Class.forName(com.mysql.jdbc.Driver). But my version of driver seems to be able to register by itself, so this solution can not work.

**Error**:

> Oct 02, 2018 9:46:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
>   reload INFO: Reloading Context with name [/WEB13] is completed
>
> java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for
>   connect URL
>   'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web13?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC'
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2224)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2104)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1563)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.dbutils.AbstractQueryRunner.prepareConnection(AbstractQueryRunner.java:319)
>     at org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner.query(QueryRunner.java:327)
>     at com.itheima.login.LoginServlet.doGet(LoginServlet.java:36)   at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver     at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)  at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2209)
>     ... 29 more

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot create JDBC driver of class ' ' for connect URL 'null' : I do not understand this exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516747/cannot-create-jdbc-driver-of-class-for-connect-url-null-i-do-not-underst)

Comment: may be you are missing some methods as described [here](http://www.codeblogbt.com/archives/80075#cnblogs_code_open_6be44ef6-9d8c-45b7-865e-bf34d94615f6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your properties file is missing a property, which means the DBCP is not able to create/initialize the driver.

You need to add

```
driverClassName = org.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ziyan Zhu,

You have added wrong url in `db.properties`:

url in db properties be like `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web13` where web13 is your database name.

In addition you are missing some method in your connection pool as described over [here](http://www.codeblogbt.com/archives/80075#cnblogs_code_open_6be44ef6-9d8c-45b7-865e-bf34d94615f6)

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory;

public class DBCPUtils {
    private static DataSource dataSource;
    static {
        try {
            // 1.Load the properties file input stream
            InputStream is = DBCPUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("db.properties");
            // 2.Load the input stream
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.load(is);
            // 3.create data source
            dataSource = BasicDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(props);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static DataSource getDataSource() {
        return dataSource;
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            return dataSource.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i just had the same problem, but i was working with glassfish. if there is anyone in the future who has this problem attempting establishing a database connection in glassfish server, the solutions is to add `java mysql connector` to glassfish server then your problem is solved.

***go to .../glassfish-installation-folder/Glassfish[your-version]/glassfish/lib/here-paste-your-mysql-connector-driver.jar***

it's my pleasure. :)