# Tomcat JNDI data source error "No suitable driver"

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, jdbc, jndi

We are Migrating Struts 1.2 project from JDK 1.6 to 1.8 and application server jboss5.1 to tomcat 8.5. So we started chaining JNDI data source to tomcat but it seems I’m missing something because I’m getting an error
`"java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver"` but I have added ojdbc driver and configurations.

Database is Oracle 12C.

Here are steps which did it

1. Added database configuration in context.xml under tomcat/conf

   ```
   <Resource name="jdbc/Test" 
      auth="Container" 
      type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
      maxTotal="100" 
      maxIdle="30" 
      maxWaitMillis="10000" 
      username="xxxxx" 
      password="xxxxx" 
      driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" 
      url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxx:1527:xxxx" />
   ```
2. Added data source reference in web.xml under {project}/WEB-INF/web.xml

   ```
   <resource-ref>
      <description>Oracle Datasource</description>
      <res-ref-name>jdbc/Test</res-ref-name>
      <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
      <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
   </resource-ref>
   ```
3. Sample code

   ```
   public static void dbInit(String dataSourceRef) throws Exception {
       Context ctx = new InitialContext();
       static DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/" +
           dataSourceRef);
   }
   ```
4. Added `ojdbc8.jar` file under tomcat/lib.

Error:

```
Nov 06, 2019 4:48:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/8.5.47
    Nov 06, 2019 4:48:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    Nov 06, 2019 4:48:22 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
    Nov 06, 2019 4:48:22 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
    INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
    Nov 06, 2019 4:48:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
    INFO: Initialization processed in 1410 ms
    Nov 06, 2019 4:48:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
    INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
    Nov 06, 2019 4:48:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
    INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.47
    Nov 06, 2019 4:48:28 PM org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory getObjectInstance
    **INFO: Name = Test Ignoring unknown property: value of "Oracle Datasource" for "description" property**
    Nov 06, 2019 4:48:34 PM org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory getObjectInstance
    Nov 06, 2019 4:48:34 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
    INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
    Nov 06, 2019 4:48:34 PM org.apache.struts.util.PropertyMessageResources <init>
    INFO: Initializing, config='org.apache.struts.util.LocalStrings', returnNull=true
    Nov 06, 2019 4:48:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
    Nov 06, 2019 4:48:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    INFO: Server startup in 12576 ms
    Nov 06, 2019 4:48:35 PM org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor initDefinitionsMapping
    INFO: Tiles definition factory found for request processor ''.
    Nov 06, 2019 4:48:36 PM org.apache.struts.util.PropertyMessageResources <init>
    INFO: Initializing, config='org.apache.struts.actions.LocalStrings', returnNull=true
    Nov 06, 2019 4:48:36 PM com.db.DbQuery getStatusCodesCount
    SEVERE: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
    Nov 06, 2019 4:48:36 PM org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor processException
    WARNING: Unhandled Exception thrown: class java.sql.SQLException
    Nov 06, 2019 4:48:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [action] threw exception
    java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DriverFactory.createDriver(DriverFactory.java:60)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:472)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:538)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:753)
        at com...db.DbQuery.getStatusCodesCount(DbQuery.java:983)
        at com...actions.Action.executeDisplay(Action.java:385)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:280)
        at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:216)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:507)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:470)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1069)
        at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:274)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:455)
        at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(TilesRequestProcessor.java:320)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:279)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:507)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:470)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:742)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:712)
        at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:110)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:528)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:810)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    Nov 06, 2019 4:48:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [action] threw exception
    java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DriverFactory.createDriver(DriverFactory.java:60)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:472)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:538)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:753)
        at com.db.DbQuery.getStatusCodesCount(DbQuery.java:983)
        at com.actions.Action.executeDisplay(Action.java:385)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:280)
        at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:216)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:507)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:470)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1069)
        at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:274)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:455)
        at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(TilesRequestProcessor.java:320)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:279)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:507)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:470)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:742)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:712)
        at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:110)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:528)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:810)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    Nov 06, 2019 4:48:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/code] threw exception [javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'] with root cause
    java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DriverFactory.createDriver(DriverFactory.java:60)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:472)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:538)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:753)
        at com.db.DbQuery.getStatusCodesCount(DbQuery.java:983)
        at com.actions.Action.executeDisplay(Action.java:385)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:280)
        at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:216)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:507)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:470)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1069)
        at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:274)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:455)
        at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(TilesRequestProcessor.java:320)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:279)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:507)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:470)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:742)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:712)
        at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:110)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:528)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:810)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Test code:

I was trying below code and it worked fine without any issue. But still have problem to connect through JNDI.

```
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
 "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl", "system", "Password123")) {
 if (conn != null) {
  System.out.println("Connected to the database!");
 } else {
  System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
 }
} catch (SQLException e) {
 System.err.format("SQL State: %s\n%s", e.getSQLState(), e.getMessage());
} catch (Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Appreciate your help

Comment: does it work if you move the jar file to the applications lib directory?

Comment: Nope, Still same error.

Comment: does the context lookup work?  Maybe better to post your stack trace.

Comment: Just posted error, Please let me know what is the issue.

Comment: See https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html - have you a context.xml ?

Comment: Yes, i did refer link which you shared also few other tomcat-8.5 doc as well. All looks same as the tomcat doc and no difference.

Comment: Are you sure your driver has been picked up correctly ?

Comment: IMO, if step 1 is done then step 2 is not required!

Comment: No, i don't think it picked up correctly. Because Data source name ignored but question is why got ignored. **INFO: Name = Test Ignoring unknown property: value of "Oracle Datasource" for "description" property**
    Nov 06, 20

Comment: Did you tried to test `DriverManager.registerDriver(new
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
conn =
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:oci8:@database","username","password");` as suggested here https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html

Comment: Yes, I tried to test with sample code as per tomcat doc and it worked fine. Also i updated in the question section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several answers as [@ChristopherSchultz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516747/cannot-create-jdbc-driver-of-class-for-connect-url-null-i-do-not-underst) suggest you need to put `context.xml` in folder webapp/META-INF/

> Don't put anything in Tomcat's `conf/context.xml`: there's really no reason for it. Instead, use your webapp's `META-INF/context.xml` to define your `<Resource>`.